# Column processing in Unix

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk

My input file has

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
111,0.1, 0.5,[a,b,c,d],
```

I want to split the value in col4 by comma and put first 3 those values in col5, col6, col7, ignore from 4th value.

Expected output:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
111,0.1, 0.5,[a,b,c,d],a,b,c
```

Please help.

I have used below commands:

```
echo "col1\tcol2\tcol3\tcol4\tcol5\tcol6\tcol7" >> cipoc_output.csv
awk -F"," '$1=$1' OFS="\t" cipoc_input.csv >> cipoc_output.csv
cat cipoc_output.csv
```

Comment: I tried using awk, sed and cut commands. But not able to get it exactly

Comment: @anubhava added

Comment: That code you added has nothing at all to do with the problem you described - all it does is print a header and change commas to tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{print; next} {o=$0; gsub(/[][]/,""); print o $4, $5, $6}' file
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
111,0.1, 0.5,[a,b,c,d],a,b,c
```

If that isn't all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that that doesn't work for.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `gnu awk` with `FPAT`:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\[[^]]*]|[^,]+' 'NR > 1 {
   s=$4
   gsub(/^\[|,[^,]+\]$/, "", s)
   $0 = $0 s
} 1' file
```

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
111,0.1, 0.5,[a,b,c,d],a,b,c
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in https://ideone.com/o0slbt

```
awk '
FNR==1{ print; next }
match($0,/\[[^]]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  start=RSTART
  end=RSTART+RLENGTH
  match(val,/.*,/)
  print substr($0,1,start) substr(val,RSTART+1,RLENGTH) substr($0,end) substr(val,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
  val=start=end=""
  next
}
1
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sed` solution, assuming there are not any extreme characters around.

```
> sed -e 's/\[\([^][]*\),[^,]*\],/&\1/g' file
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
111,0.1, 0.5,[a,b,c,d],a,b,c
```